# C# WPF - How can i preselect ListView Items programmatically using the .IsSelected property?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

I have a C# WPF application and using ListView with basically works fine.
My issue is:
I want to preselect items in the list view. The selection should be visible for the user, and the user should be able to modify the selection.

I tried prototyping with a very simple application.

Here ist my XAML Code:

```
<Grid>
        <ListView Name="lvEntries" SelectionMode="Multiple" Margin="0,0,0,116">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Lastname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Firstname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And here my code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lvEntries.Items.Clear();
            Person newPerson = new Person();
            newPerson.FirstName = "Jack";
            newPerson.LastName = "Nicholson";
            lvEntries.Items.Add(newPerson);
            Person newPerson2 = new Person();
            newPerson2.FirstName = "Bill";
            newPerson2.LastName = "Murray";
            lvEntries.Items.Add(newPerson2);
        }
}

public class Person
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Everything fine so far.
Now i would like to make a pre-selection.
The ListViewItem Class has a .IsSelected property, which can be theoretically set in code-behind.
But

```
lvEntries.Items[0].IsSelected = true;
```

or

```
newPerson.IsSelected = true;
```

is not available.

Then i tried to derive the class "Person" from ListViewItem - now .IsSelected is available.
Now the C# code looks like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lvEntries.Items.Clear();
            Person newPerson = new Person();
            newPerson.FirstName = "Jack";
            newPerson.LastName = "Nicholson";
            newPerson.IsSelected = true;
            lvEntries.Items.Add(newPerson);
            Person newPerson2 = new Person();
            newPerson2.FirstName = "Bill";
            newPerson2.LastName = "Murray";
            newPerson2.IsSelected = true;
            lvEntries.Items.Add(newPerson2);
        }
    }

public class Person : ListViewItem
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

The result is funny:
I can see the selected lines after starting the app.
But the lines does not have content ;-) they are empty...

I think i make something basically wrong.

Is there a simple way to make a selection in a ListView with the C# code (Code-Behind) ?

Thank you very much in advance!
Emil

Comment: Try to set ListView's SelectedIndex or SelectedItem property.

Answer (score 1):

I would add `IsSelected` to the item itself. And since it seems that you also want to change which item is selected, you should also make it observable.

In this sample code, I'm using the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) NuGet package and creating ViewModels with it.

**PersonViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfListViewExample;

// The CommunityToolkit's source generators will create 
// UI-interactive properties "FirstName", "LastName" and "IsSelected" for you.
// Don't forget to make this class 'partial'.
public partial class PersonViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _firstName = string.Empty;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _lastName = string.Empty;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isSelected;
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfListViewExample;

public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        // The Smiths are selected by default.
        People.Add(new PersonViewModel { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" });
        People.Add(new PersonViewModel { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe" });
        People.Add(
            new PersonViewModel
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Smith",
                IsSelected = true,
            });
        People.Add(
            new PersonViewModel
            {
                FirstName = "Jane",
                LastName = "Smith",
                IsSelected = true,
            });
        People.Add(new PersonViewModel { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Jones" });
        People.Add(new PersonViewModel { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Jones" });
        People.Add(new PersonViewModel { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Williams" });
        People.Add(new PersonViewModel { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Williams" });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PersonViewModel> People { get; } = new();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WpfListViewExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfListViewExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    Topmost="True"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
            SelectionMode="Multiple">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn
                        Width="100"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"
                        Header="Lastname" />
                    <GridViewColumn
                        Width="100"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"
                        Header="Firstname" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile I solved it using the *.SelectedItems* property of ListView.
I simply used the `...SelectedItems.Add(..)` method to add the items I want to be selected.

I made the *MainWindow* accessible for the ViewModel Class using a global variable.
Nevertheless I think using the `IsSelected` property would be more elegant, but it works fine with `...SelectedItems.Add` and the effort is okay.